# drop down menu default options all selected

Tags: html, cgi

I was wondering how to have all the options in a drop menu (using select tags) highlighted?

I already created a button to created a select all button to do this but I want the drop menu all selected by default when arriving on the page.

It would be great if it works for IE and firefox.

thanks

Comment: If you have a button which does it, can you not just call that function on load. i.e rather than having the user press a button just call it on page load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your select is `multiple` then any `<option>` that has `selected="selected"` will be highlighted by default.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp

Comment: I'm not sure how a select can be a drop down and multiple at the same time. Though if Gordon claims to have a select-all button, then whatever functionality is called by that button can be called on document ready.

Comment: i guess you are right, i should just call it on document ready